# How to used Transient keyword in entity class according to condition?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I have Spring-Boot with Spring data project when I connect that to **Person table in database 1** it is working perfectly. Now when I connect same codebase to **Person table in database 2 where that table have two more extra column** which is not in my entity.

Now my first question is to fixed this what are possible approach?

Second question is: How could I use Transient keyword when I connect to database 1 and I don't want to use Transient keyword when I connect to database 2?

Comment: Would it be OK for you to create separate classes? I mean if the data in different DBs are different then you could easier separate the data also in code level.

Comment: Thanks but this will not work , We want to use same entity class. Actually if we go for your suggested approach then there two separate table will create in database . We want to used same entity person for Person table in both database .[in 2 database  two column are more which is not in entity. ] Data is same in both database only in second database two column are extra.

Comment: You can use two entities with different packages and control there involvement in the JPA using component scan.
You can use different profiles names for DB1 and DB2 , so based on requirement enable particular profile.

Comment: And for your second question no - you cannot use transient based on condition.

Comment: Thanks Lucia , Could you please guide me with any article if you know so that I can try that. That will be very grateful.